# AVFoundation video playback issue

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, arkit

I've followed along with [this excellent tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FKzSYAGfJ0) from Yuma and have something working. Below is the code that I'm using in my viewcontroller

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit
import AVFoundation
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self

        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true

        // Create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/notebook.scn")!

        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()

        guard let arImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else { return }
        configuration.trackingImages = arImages
        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard anchor is ARImageAnchor else { return }

        // Amy Image recognition
        guard let amyContainer = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "amy", recursively: false) else { return }
        amyContainer.removeFromParentNode()
        node.addChildNode(amyContainer)
        amyContainer.isHidden = false

        // Video
        let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4")!

        let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

        let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 900.0, height: 1400.0))

        let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: videoPlayer)

        videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width / 2, y: videoScene.size.height / 2)

        videoNode.size = videoScene.size

        videoNode.yScale = -1

        videoNode.play()

        videoScene.addChild(videoNode)

        guard let video = amyContainer.childNode(withName: "video", recursively: true)
        else { return }
    video.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene

 }
 }
```

When I use the video that was supplied as part of the tutorial everything works perfectly, but when I try and include a video that I've created I only get a white box over the target image, but no video.

I've tripled checked the name, I've tried to export the video with the exact same dimensions all with no luck.  I've tested uploading a new version of the video that does work as a different file name and changed the names and it works, so I have to assume it's the .mp4 that I'm producing which is the problem.

Are there particular rules/settings that are required for mp4's for this kind of approach, is there a setting in premiere pro or Handbrake that I can use? Or how can I debug any internal errors that are happening through Xcode itself?

Comment: did you check out my answer?

Comment: @MCMatan I checked your answer and it didn't work for me :(

Comment: I ended up going to find a contractor to help me build the app and he looked after the video and got it playing.  I tried the two answers suggested below with no luck, and I'm not going to try and resolve this any time soon.

I'm not sure what to do with the question, but will leave it here for now.

Answer (score 4):

Could be because your video size is big. You would need to wait first for **AVPlayer** to be ready before trying to play your video

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?
    var videoNode: SKVideoNode?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self

        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true

        // Create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/notebook.scn")!

        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()

        guard let arImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else { return }
        configuration.trackingImages = arImages
        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard anchor is ARImageAnchor else { return }

        // Amy Image recognition
        guard let amyContainer = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "amy", recursively: false) else { return }
        amyContainer.removeFromParentNode()
        node.addChildNode(amyContainer)
        amyContainer.isHidden = false

        let videoPlayer = self.createAVPlayer()

        let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 900.0, height: 1400.0))

        self.videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: videoPlayer)

        self.videoNode?.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width / 2, y: videoScene.size.height / 2)

        self.videoNode?.size = videoScene.size

        self.videoNode?.yScale = -1

        videoScene.addChild(self.videoNode!)

        guard let video = amyContainer.childNode(withName: "video", recursively: true)
            else { return }
        video.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene

    }

    func createAVPlayer() -> AVPlayer {
        let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4")!
        let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)

        let assetKeys = [
            "playable",
            "hasProtectedContent"
        ]
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset,
                                      automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: assetKeys)

        self.observer = playerItem.observe(\.status, options:  [.new, .old], changeHandler: { (playerItem, change) in
            if playerItem.status == .readyToPlay {

                self.videoNode?.play() // Only play when Its ready
            }
        })

        return AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I tried including this but I had the same unfortunate outcome :(  The video itself is only 9MB, and the one that works is the a little larger itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the code below without issue to play videos of varied file-size and scale.

```
    let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: videoAssetName, ofType: videoAssetExtension)!)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    videoPlayerNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)

    // setup player
    let skSceneSize = orientation == .horizontal ? CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720) : CGSize(width: 406, height: 720)
    let skScene = SKScene(size: skSceneSize)
    skScene.addChild(videoPlayerNode)

    videoPlayerNode.position = CGPoint(x: skScene.size.width/2, y: skScene.size.height/2)
    videoPlayerNode.size = skScene.size

    let scnPlaneSize : [String : CGFloat] = orientation == .horizontal ? ["width": 0.9, "height": 0.5063] : ["width": 0.5063, "height": 0.9]
    let videoPlane = SCNPlane(width: scnPlaneSize["width"]!, height: scnPlaneSize["height"]!)
    videoPlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = skScene
    videoPlane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true

    let videoPlaneNode = SCNNode(geometry: videoPlane)
    videoPlaneNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(180.degreesToRadians, 180.degreesToRadians, 0) // rotate video node to counter flip caused by contraint on adNode
    amyContainer.addChildNode(videoPlaneNode)

    // setup node to auto remove itself upon completion
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // do something on video end
        }
    })
```